# how does $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = n\bar{x}$?

Tags: statistics, summation

how does  $\sum x_i = n\bar{x}$ ?

I'm trying to understand the last step of the proof that the defining formula in stats is = to the computing formula for $S^2$

but the last part I'm not sure why $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = n\bar{x}$. I see why there is an $n$, because their is $n$ $x_i$'s when you sum them, but how does that turn it into $\bar{x}$?

the part is:

$$\frac{1}{n-1} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - 2\bar{x} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i + \sum_{i=1}^n\bar{x}^2\right)$$

and apparently in the middle part $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i= n\bar{x}$.

How??

Comment: This is hard to read.  Please provide a context and reformat using MathJax, a tutorial for which can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)).

Comment: Note:  if you are asking  about something like $\sum x_i=n\,\overline x$ where $\overline x$ denotes the average of the $x_i$ then this is just the definition of the average.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since$$\bar{x} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n}$$

Multiplying by $n$

$$n\bar{x} = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$$

Answer (score 2):

$\bar x$, I.e. mean is defined as $$\bar x=\frac{x_1+x_2+\ldots +x_n}{n}=\frac{\sum x_i}{n}$$

Thus $$\bar x=\frac{\sum x_i}{n} \implies \sum x_i=n\bar x$$
(Cross multiplication)